# Save data in dynamical text in another frame while working on current frame as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drop-down-menu, combobox

I am working on Flash actionscript 3 to create a quiz using `combobox`. I used the following code.

```
stop();
box1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeHandler);
\\box1 is combobox 1

function changeHandler(event:Event):void

{

if (box1.selectedIndex == 1)
\\there are two values in combobox with index 1 and 2

{
    name1.text = "1) Wrong";
\\name1 is the dynamical text box
}
else if (box1.selectedIndex == 2)
{
    name1.text = "1) Right";
}
else
{
    name1.text = "";
}
}
```

I put the dynamical text box on frame 4 while the combobox is in frame 2
I created two comboboxes. when I select an option from combobox 1, I get an error like this: `Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

So I extended the dynamical text layer from frame 2 to frame 4. But after running the program, the result is shown only in frame 2 immediately after selecting the value from combobox 1; so that the result is displayed before selecting combobox 2.

What I need is to save the result in frame 4 and it is displayed only when I go to that frame using `next` buttons.

Any help would be appreciated. I am beginner in Flash actionscript.(I prefer using interface than coding).

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe it's just me, but I can't quite tell what you are trying to do. You say "immediately after selecting the value from combobox 1;"... When does this happen for the user? I ask because in your code it looks like that box is used to display the result of right or wrong, yet you are saying that the problem comes "after selecting the value from combobox 1."  This is what I don't understand? Is the user selecting right or wrong? Or do you mean when flash displays right or wrong? Please explain what you want to have happen when. Probably better to not use the main timeline at all.

Comment: @NealDavis Let the values in combobox be A and B. If I select A, the output will be  "wrong". If I select B, the output will be "right".                   After I extended dynamical text layer(name1) from frame2 to frame4: The result ("right" if I select value B) is displayed exactly on the same instant on the current frame(frame2). What I need is to display the result("right" or "wrong" on frame4; while I move to net combobox.

Comment: And why are you going between frames? What is achieved by going to frame 4?

Comment: Can you post an image of your timeline?

Comment: @NealDavis See the timeline image here https://s31.postimg.org/6w1otlbt7/Capture.png

Comment: I am trying to display the results only after all questions(comboboxes) are answered. Actually I made 5 comboboxes. But for the simplicity I just mentioned two.

Comment: stop coding in the timeline.  You will thank me.  Write you script in an .as file.  It looks like you are changing fairly minor things in the display by going to new frames.  When you go to a new frame, the code on the other frames isn't read anymore, so storing variables etc. becomes very difficult, to say nothing of writing functions.  Your app has reached the complexity level that truly necessitates switching to .as files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output should be displayed if all conditions are met.  So the code might look something like this

```
if (condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: But how can I display the result in frame 4?

Comment: That's a good question.  Why do you need to be on frame 4?  I'm trying to understand why you are doing so much on the timeline.  There is probably a much better way to do it all on the first frame of the main timeline.

Comment: Because I need to show the result from all comboxes together when I click ("click to see result" ) button in frame 3. I need to add some more tests after finishing this.

Comment: Right, but you don't need to go to a new frame to do this.  What is so special about frame 4?  What is on it that can't just be added to frame 1 and removed as needed?  This can all be done so easily in AS3 without the main timeline.

Comment: I m sorry. I don't know the alternate option for this. I just created a frame for displaying result. So can you explain the method you mean; by removing data from frame 1??

Comment: all display objects have a property called .visible. Set that to true or false as needed

Comment: Or you can dynamically set their alpha to 0 or 1 or dynamically change their x or y position to off the stage or on the stage.